# Using forloop.counter to iterate over list in django template

Tags: python, django

I have a list of objects named `chargers_list` and on my view I estimate when will the charging be done. List of estimates is the same size and is named `eta`. I iterate over chargers `{% for charger in charger_list %}` to display some information about every charger. Inside that loop I want to print estimated time. Simple `ETA: {{eta.0|date:'Y-m-d H:i'}}` works if I provide the index. But how can I utilize forloop.counter (that's the only way I thought of doing this)? When I simply `ETA: {{eta.forloop.counter|date:'Y-m-d H:i'}}` it throws an error:

```
Exception Type: TemplateSyntaxError
Exception Value:    
Could not parse some characters: eta|[forloop.counter]||date:'Y-m-d H:i'
```

Comment: If I'm understanding your problem correctly, you have a `chargers_list` and each element of `chargers_list` is a `charger` object that has a list of `eta`s that are all the same size?

Comment: @Scratch'N'Purr no, sorry, I could've been more clear with that. I have `charger_list` with `charger` objects and `eta` list with separate times for every charger. So first "time" from `eta` list is estimated time for first `charger`

Comment: Got it. In this case, I would [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) the `charger_list` and `eta` list. This would generate an iterable of tuples where the tuple would have a structure like `(<charger>, <time>)`. Pass this iterable as a context variable to the template.